# Robustness of a dictionary to prevent extra spaces

Tags: c#, regex, dictionary

I'm using a dictionary and all the keys come from a text file. I have to iterate through a dictionary to set the values of another array. The array population function looks like this:

```
destination_array[i, name_column_dictionary[name[i]] = matching_symbols[i].value;
```

However, in the array named `name` in my example, there is an extra space at the end of one entry. I can't change this array since it's generated by another program. Is there a way to make the verification eliminate every extra space at the end? I was thinking of using a temporary variable to store the data with a regex. Would regex be a solution?

In other words, given `destination_array[i, name_column_dictionary[my string ]`, I would like it to be considered as `destination_array[i, name_column_dictionary[my string]`.

Edit: my question is different from the one associated with it because I'd like to use regex. It would be even better if it could prevent any extra space (`"my  string"` considered as `"my string"`).

Comment: To be clear - are you saying your dict has an entry for `d["my string "]` and, when someone asks for `d["my string"]` you want the dictionary to return the value of `d["my string "]`?

Comment: No, the other way around. My dictionary keys don't have any extra space and I'd like ``dictionary[" my  string ]`` to be considered as ``dictionary["my string"] to prevent any errors.

Comment: You didn't even mention regex which were part of the question. Could you reopen the question? I would have preferred if you had waited for clarification before closing my question, since reopening a question is always very long and not beginners-welcoming. You asked for clarification 15 minutes after I asked the question and closed the question 6 minutes later but 3 hours after I asked to reopen it's still closed.

Comment: Could you include in the question a minimal example that includes all the types, defines all the variables, demonstrates the actual behavior/output, and shows/explains the desirable behavior? Ideally it should be a small console application with up to 20 lines of code, that can compile as is on [.Net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/) or [SharpLab](https://sharplab.io/).

Comment: The linked question would still the the right answer, just with a different definition of "equal". You _could_ use regex to determine if two strings are "equal" ignoring whitespace, sure, but it seems to be a preference more than a requirement (and could be asked independent of dictionaries).

Answer (score 2):

You can simply just make use of [TrimEnd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.trimend?view=net-8.0)

```
destination_array[i, name_column_dictionary[myString.TrimEnd()];
```

Comment: It doesn't really solve the problem and it doesn't use regex.